# Why program interface is change when i run it on screen?

Tags: linux, terminal, gnu-screen

Sorry for my english first of all.
Why program interface is change when i run it on screen?

without screen

```
                                +--------[ Қош келдіңіздер! ]--------+
                                |                                    |
                                | Введите Ваше имя : usr             |
                                | Пароль           :                 |
                                |                                    |
                                +------------------------------------+
```

with screen

```
                                           ош келдіңіздер! ]--------+
                                +--------[ 
                                |                                    |
                                | Введите Ваше имя : usr             |
                                | Пароль           :                 |
                                |                                    |
                                +------------------------------------+
```

Comment: I'm guessing it has to do with the 'Қ' character which is causing a return in screen. I suggest you try escaping it or replacing it by its unicode so that screen interprets it properly.

Comment: Yes it's work. But how i can avoid the problem without changing the character?

Comment: Try to look at encoding schemes or something of the sort. This should be a good reference: http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Character-Processing

Comment: If possible use UTF-8 encoding (not some KOI...).